# Wordpress returning all posts when there's no results

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have the following query:

```
$params = array(
    'post_type'             => array('health-and-rehab', 'community'),
    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
    'orderby'               => 'meta_value',
    'order'                 => 'ASC'
);

query_posts($params);
```

But when the query have no results, it returns all the posts and I don't want this to happen. The other problem that I'm facing is with the "found_posts" that always returns 0, no matter what are the results.

How can I fix the "found_posts" and how can I return 0 posts when there's no results?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not a proper answer, but I still have no privileges to comment:

It is not recommended to use `query_posts`, you might be interfering with the main query. See this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

That post helped me a lot.

Anyway you should give more info in order to check your actual loop(s).

Comment: I already tested the other 2 ways of queries but I got the same results.

Comment: Are you cleaning up previous queries? And again, I'm no pro, but those who are will need more code in order to help you...